# How to solve system of 4 equations with four unknowns?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have got system of 4 equations as shown below and I am considering if there is any other method than brute force to solve them.

```
B + C + D = S1
A + C + D = S2
A + B + D = S3
A + B + C = S4
```

Values of S1-S4 are given:

```
S1 = 70
S2 = 75
S3 = 80
S4 = 75
```

I tried to to solve that, but always I have infinite equation what means to solve `A` I need `B`, to solve `B` I need `C`, to solve `C` I need `D` and to solve `D` I need.. `A`. I know the answer, but need the solution how to solve it. Answer:

```
A = 30
B = 25
C = 20
D = 25
```

Comment: a) what exactly did you try? and, b) it is a very bad idea to use capital letters (or functions starting with capital letters), as they are reserved for system symbols. This is definitely the case for `C`, `D`. Use small letters instead. Also see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users

Comment: `Solve[{b + c + d == S1, a + c + d == S2, a + b + d == S3, 
  a + b + c == S4}, {a, b, c, d}]`??

Comment: I tried to change the equations to other forms like `A = S3 - S1 + C` or `A = S2 - C - D`. I am thinking about on paper solution, without using any built-in functions. In this case it doesn't matter if I use capital or small letters.

Comment: @Kobra In that case, you want [math.se], not this site. This is a site for users of _Mathematica_, a software.

Comment: yep, voting to migrate

Comment: Oh, thank you for indicate, I didn't notice the difference between the Mathematics and Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you subtract the last from the third, you get $D-C=-1$ or $D=C-1$.  Now you can substitute this into three equations and eliminate $D$.  Similarly subtracting the first two allows you to eliminate $B$  You will then have two equations in two unknowns, and again can solve one equation for one unknown in terms of the other.  This is a standard technique for simultaneous equations, which works very well with this set because of the structure.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did it! :) , `A = (S4 + S3 + S2 - 2 * S1) / 3`, `B = A + S1 - S2`, `C = S4 - A - B`, `D = C + S3 - S4`

Answer (score 6):

Use Gaussian elimination/method:

Your equation becomes:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 75         \\[0.55ex]
      1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 80        \\[0.55ex]
      1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 75\\[0.55ex]
      0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 70
\end{array}\right]$$

You can multiply rows and add/subtract them from another row, which will not affect the solution. So you can subtract the first row from the second and the thirdrow and the matrix will become:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 75         \\[0.55ex]
      0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 5        \\[0.55ex]
      0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\[0.55ex]
      0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 70
\end{array}\right]$$

Now add the third row to the fourth:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 75         \\[0.55ex]
      0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 5        \\[0.55ex]
      0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\[0.55ex]
      0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 70
\end{array}\right]$$

And at last add the second row to the fourth row:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
      1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 75         \\[0.55ex]
      0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 5        \\[0.55ex]
      0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\[0.55ex]
      0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 75
\end{array}\right]$$

Now from the last row we get that $3D = 75 \implies D=25$

From the third row we get that $D-B = 0 \implies D=B \implies B=25$

From the second row we get that $D-C = 5 \implies C=25-5 \implies C=20$

And from the first row we get that: $A+B+C = 75 \implies A=30$

Answer (score 0):

If you add all systems to each other you will get:

3(A+B+C+D)=300 so A+B+C+D=100

Then use this equation to find out A, B, C and D

For example: B+C+D=70 and A+B+C+D=100 
subtract the systems to each other you'll find A=30.

Answer (score -1):

B=D
So use the first equation b+c+d=b+c+b=70
and the second a+c+d=75
and the third a+b+d=80
so b-c=5
(b+c+b+5) divided by 3 equals b and d
(70+5) divided by 3 equals 25(b and d)
25-5=20(c)
(a+c+b)-(b+c+b)=5(a-b)
25+5=30(a)
a=30
b=25
c=20
d=25